# QProcess can't start python script

Tags: python, c++, qt, qprocess

The problem is that the python script doesn't run. I expect to see an output file (tmp.json) in the directory but I do not. There are some questions with the same issue but the solutions did not work for me. The python.exe path is correct as I used to use python.h instead of Qprocess to embed python.

**main**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QProcess>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    
    QProcess p;
    QStringList params;
    params << "F:/NLP/google_corpus/scrape_python/qt/cpy2/someFunction.py";
    p.start("C:/Users/A/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe", params);
    QString p_stdout = p.readAll();
    QString p_stderr = p.readAllStandardError();
    if ( p.state() == QProcess::NotRunning ) {
        return -2;
    };
    p.waitForFinished(-1);

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**someFunction.py**

```
import json
with open('F:\NLP\google_corpus\scrape_python\qt\cpy2tmp.json', 'w') as json_obj:
        json.dump(2, json_obj)
```

Comment: What is the source of your inconsistency that you are using `/` to separate directries in your C++ code but trying to use ``\`` in Python code?

Comment: Does QProcess accept forward slashes?  The CreateProcess API is one of the only Win32 APIs that does not accept forward slashes in paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character `\` is used for escape sequences in Python, so you should write `\\` to express `\` in strings.

```
import json
with open('F:\\NLP\\google_corpus\\scrape_python\\qt\\cpy2tmp.json', 'w') as json_obj:
        json.dump(2, json_obj)
```

Comment: This is almost certainly the problem, because `\N` does have meaning in a Python string.